# readlines() cannot read lines after using readline()

Tags: python

The following simple code reads a CSV file and returns the number of lines of the file. As you can see in the output, the file has 501 lines.

```
>>> import codecs
>>> f = codecs.open("tmp.csv", "r", "utf_8")
>>> print len(f.readlines())
501
```

But if I insert a readline() before using readlines(), the latter does not reach at the end of the file.

```
>>> import codecs
>>> f = codecs.open("tmp.csv", "r", "utf_8")
>>> f.readline()
>>> print len(f.readlines())
1
```

Is there any basic mistake in my code? How can I mix readline() and readlines()? (actually I don't need to mix these two functions in my real program, but I am just curious...)

You can download the file at
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/16653989/tmp/tmp.csv

Comment: Reproduces with Python 2.7.5 (OS X) and Python 2.6.6 (Scientific Linux 6.4)

Comment: Why would you want to read first one line and then all the file?

Comment: No need to read the first line separately, but I just wanted to know why this code did not work as expected.

I my actual code, the first line in the file is a comment header, and the rest is data. So I first tried to do `header = f.readline(); data = f.readlines()`

But due to this problem, I do `lines = f.readlines(); header = lines[0]; data = lines[1:]` now.

Comment: Looks like the bug has been fixed recently also in Python 2.7, but there has not been a release of 2.7 since. http://bugs.python.org/issue8260

Comment: Thank you. I tried the latest codecs.py http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/e24265eb2271/Lib/codecs.py but it didn't solve my problem. I will send my report to the developers.

Answer (score 3):

This has something to do with the `codecs` module. Because when you do the same thing with the regular python `open` statement, it works as expected:

```
f = open('tmp.csv')
f.readline()
>>> print len(f.readlines())
500
```

Comment: @AkiraOkumura, I was just reading about your problem and found that others have had this problem as well. It is a bug with codec. Hope that helps

Comment: Thank you again. I will try the link Janne told me.